# How to put cs: with NASM style?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I found something when I was reverse engineering a binary, there were the following instructions:

`nop     word ptr cs:[eax+eax+00000000h]`

I am having trouble re-writing the assembly code above in the NASM style, especially the `cs:` section are there any specific tricks ?

I wrote `nop     word [eax+eax+00000000h]` already correct ?

Comment: It has to go inside the brackets.

Comment: Have you tried disassembling it with `ndisasm -b32` to find out the correct NASM syntax for that machine code?  Or Agner Fog's `objconv` has a NASM disassembly mode.  This technique should cover this and most other syntax details.

Comment: You may also need to put `dword` inside the brackets to tell nasm to use a dword offset. (Or you could use an offset value that won’t fit in a byte.)